# Extract unique character strings in R

Tags: r

I have 40 CSV files. In each, there is a column of names. In each name column the same name may be repeated (in total, the name column on average has 20,000 rows and about half are unique). I want to create a list of the names that appear in more than one file (while being told which files the appear in). If the same name appears in more than one file, I would like to know the name of each.

So, on a small scale:

```
  File1
  Name
  John
  Peter
  Abby
  John


  File2
  Mike
  Tim
  John
  Anothername


  File3
  Me
  Mike
  Adam
  Eve
```

My desired output would be something like:

```
data.frame
Names         File
John           1
John           2
Mike           2
Mike           3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach yo might take if you put all your csvs into a list:

```
#generate a fake data set easy to work with
LIST <- lapply(rpois(10, 10), function(i)data.frame(id=1:i, state=sample(state.name, i)))

#add the file number as a column
v <- lapply(1:length(LIST), function(i)data.frame(LIST[[i]], file=rep(i, nrow( LIST[[i]]))))

#make one big data frame
dat <- do.call(rbind, v)[, -1]

#reorder said data frame
dat[order(dat$state, dat$file), ]
```

Comment: this takes me most of the way there. But how do I modify this to first extract the name column from the larger data frame that each file contains?

Comment: considering I have about 20,000 names in each file, the data.frame gets too large to handle. length(unique(file_name$Name)) for first file is a factor of 9483. When I convert this to a list so I can use it in a data frame, R crashes.

Comment: Its ok. I figured out how to do it. thanks though! I learned a bit from your answer!